# Upload file from google drive to my web app when user selects file from google drive picker

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am new to meteorJs framework. I have a use case like when an user clicks on a button  google drive picker has to open after google authentication and when user select any file from the google drive that file should get uploaded to my collection(or if I get the readable stream can I upload the stream to my s3 bucket and can I view that file in front end ?).

How do I achieve this process in meteorJs ?
Can any one please explain, It will be very help full.

Comment: Can anyone help me with code for google file picker in Meteorjs?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Meteor based question . But generally you would achieve this as you would using vanilla javascript . You could set this up in Meteor in a `Template.onRendered` callback or `Tracker.autorun` ,or anywhere convenient for you.

NB:  Make sure your function doesn't execute before the Template is created .

I assume you know how to get blob/data from google driver api in your desired format.

Then you could check out these

1. https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection
2. https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files
3. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/gridfs/

Let me know if I helped .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).